# prove+ perfect passive

Tags: grammar

X did something when he was alive. His biographies tell what he did in his life. There are reports about his action he did. Is this grammatical? ['It' refers to some particular act, e.g. he celebrated some event.]

**It proves to have been done by X.**

The speaker wants to say: It has been reported in books and thus it has been proved that he did that particular thing.

Note: The word 'prove' is necessary because people make his doings the base for doing things.

Comment: **It proves to....** (except **It proves to someone..**) is not grammatical.

Comment: @RonaldSole *Au contraire*; what about uses like "If it proves to be of use to the family..."?

Comment: @stangdon "To be shown to be such; turn out" (intransitive) is not the same thing as "to show that something is true by providing facts, information etc" (transitive). The dictionary definition proves there is a difference. If my assertion proves accurate, you should upvote my comment. :)

Comment: @stangdon Touché! A palpable hit! I stand corrected.